# Getting user input on screen in pygame and how to store it

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pickle, pyinstaller

I have a small python arcade game that I've converted to a standalone .exe using pyInstaller. It works fine with pygame, but the issue is that I use pickle to save highscores. I was originally using cmd for user input, so in cmd it would say "Please type your name" and whatever you typed would be stored in a separate file using pickle. Two problems: I can't use cmd in the standalone .exe (and it looks ugly anyways), and when I store it in a separate file with pickle, I don't think it's being included in the standalone. I say "think" because the code never makes it's way past the user input section.

How can I get the user input to appear on the screen (in my own font and location) rather than in cmd?

and

How can I include the user input file (which is stored with pickle) to be included in the .exe?

This is what I have currently (all within the main loop):

```
if lives == 0:
    username = input("Please type your name: ")
    highscore = {username: points}
    try:
        with open("C:/Python35/highscore.txt", "rb") as highscoreBest:
            highscoreBest = pickle.load(highscoreBest)

    except EOFError:
        with open("C:/Python35/highscore.txt", "wb") as highscoreBest:
            pickle.dump(highscore, highscoreBest)

    for (k, v), (k2, v2) in zip(highscore.items(), highscoreBest.items()):
        if v >= v2:
            with open("C:/Python35/highscore.txt", "wb") as highscoreBest:
                pickle.dump(highscore, highscoreBest)

    with open("C:/Python35/highscore.txt", "rb") as highscoreBest:
        highscoreBest = pickle.load(highscoreBest)

    for key, value in highscoreBest.items():
        print("%s has the highscore of %s!" % (key, value))
        highscoreText = highscorefont.render("Highscore %s" % (value), 1, textcolor)

    gameOverText = font.render("GAME OVER", 1, textcolor)
    scoreText = font.render("Score  %s" % (points), 1, textcolor)

    while 1:
        screen.blit(gameOverText, (200, 400))
        screen.blit(scoreText, (225, 450))
        screen.blit(highscoreText, (235,500))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Thank you to all who reply.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want to have GUI in your game. Read this http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui, it should help you.

For example,

```
OcempGUI

Links

Home Page:  http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/gui.html
Source:     http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=100329&package_id=149654
Installation http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/manual/installation.html
```

Regarding text file for highscores you can include into the bundle along with executable file, see https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

```
Adding Data Files
To have data files included in the bundle, provide a list that describes the files as the value of the datas= argument to Analysis. The list of data files is a list of tuples. Each tuple has two values, both of which must be strings:

The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
The second specifies the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time.
For example, to add a single README file to the top level of a one-folder app, you could modify the spec file as follows:

a = Analysis(...
     datas=[ ('src/README.txt', '.') ],
     ...
     )
You have made the datas= argument a one-item list. The item is a tuple in which the first string says the existing file is src/README.txt. That file will be looked up (relative to the location of the spec file) and copied into the top level of the bundled app.
```

Comment: I know that I can bundle it with the exe, but I am unaware of how to do so with pyInstaller since it automatically bundles the files that I need, so I don't know how to manually add one. Also, I don't know how to install any of these "GUI Libraries." Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, but what do I do with the `.gz` file that I downloaded for OcempGUI? All of the "extract" options are grayed out.